# I got 2 bountied questions, but the system thinks it's 3

Tags: bug, bounty, deleted-questions, profile-page

Today I logged in to SO to see that apparently one of my [bountied questions got deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087296/ie-8-accept-header-does-not-include-text-html-on-window-location-href-replace), apparently by Community's automated clean-up.

Now, however, the system still thinks I have 3 active bounties, while it should be only 2:

[image: Wrong number of bounties]

See how it has a `3` on the bounties tab. It does say `2 active bounties` though.

However, apart from this inconsistency which may just be a harmless glitch, the `start a bounty` link does not appear underneath any question for me! I think my third bounty slot should have been freed when the question was deleted.

Comment: I don't know whether this bug applies to other SE sites, in that case someone should migrate this to meta SE.

Comment: You don't need to move it to MSE, the SE team will see it here, so it is fine to ask it here.  But for this question, was it that the question was removed (i.e. deleted) or the bounty was removed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 the entire question is gone. I find it strange that no notification of this appeared, but I saw that I suddenly got 50 rep and went to investigate.

Comment: Since the bounty would have prevented deletion, i'm guessing a mod manually refunded the bounty before deleting it.  If you have a link to the question, you'll be able to see what happened (who deleted the post, which would likely be the same mod who canceled the bounty).  But the wrong count is likely caching.  It should straighten itself out on its own soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087296/ie-8-accept-header-does-not-include-text-html-on-window-location-href-replace - this deleted question has an active bounty... _deleted by Community♦ 12 hours ago_

Comment: @MAt ok, that would be a bug since the bounty is supposed to prevent that.

Comment: @Mat yeah that was my deleted question.

Comment: I have manually removed the bounty from the deleted question. There is a bug there somewhere, for certain.

Comment: @Oded The 50 rep from the bounty is now reimbursed twice for me. I now got 50 rep too much. Not that I complain but... ;)

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester what does it say when you go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?  Does it show your correct rep without the extra 50?  Or does it show the extra 50?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I got +50 yesterday - removed, +50 today - bounty (same question)

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I understand that, but does it show that in the `/reputation` page?  If so, that is a larger bug.  If not, then your reputation shown on the site will eventually catch up.  It won't show the actual refunds, but at the bottom of that page will be your actual reputation.

Comment: @psubsee2003 the "actual reputation" on the page you linked to is correct.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester then the issue is just your displayed reputation.  It will self correct the next time your reputation is recommputed.  But the bug that caused the deleted question in the first place is not solved.

Comment: I thought the numbers on the tabs always show the results since you last opened, then closed or refreshed the tab.  I have (9) responses in my tabs currently, as soon as I visit that tab they will be gone.  In your case, you say that you open this tab and notice you only have 3.  That seems consistent with the other tabs as you _had_ 3 open bounties when you last went to your profile page.